# Is there a faster way to create 12 buttons?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, interface

I am doing a task where I need to create a 3x4 GridLayout with 12 buttons. The task is when I click any of the buttons, all other buttons change the value to 1. Now, this is how I did it:

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300,200);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));
    
    JButton b1=new JButton("1");
    JButton b2=new JButton("2");
    JButton b3=new JButton("3");
    JButton b4=new JButton("4");
    JButton b5=new JButton("5");
    JButton b6=new JButton("6");
    JButton b7=new JButton("7");
    JButton b8=new JButton("8");
    JButton b9=new JButton("9");
    JButton b10=new JButton("10");
    JButton b11=new JButton("11");
    JButton b12=new JButton("12");

    b1.addActionListener(lambdaExpression -> {
        b2.setText("1");
        b3.setText("1");
        b4.setText("1");
        b5.setText("1");
        b6.setText("1");
        b7.setText("1");
        b8.setText("1");
        b9.setText("1");
        b10.setText("1");
        b11.setText("1");
        b12.setText("1");

    });

    b2.addActionListener(lambdaExpression -> {
        b1.setText("1");
        b3.setText("1");
        b4.setText("1");
        b5.setText("1");
        b6.setText("1");
        b7.setText("1");
        b8.setText("1");
        b9.setText("1");
        b10.setText("1");
        b11.setText("1");
        b12.setText("1");

    });
    
    b3.addActionListener(lambdaExpression -> {
        b1.setText("1");
        b2.setText("1");
        b4.setText("1");
        b5.setText("1");
        b6.setText("1");
        b7.setText("1");
        b8.setText("1");
        b9.setText("1");
        b10.setText("1");
        b11.setText("1");
        b12.setText("1");

    });
    .
    .
    .
    frame.add(b1);
    frame.add(b2);
    frame.add(b3);
    .
    .
    .
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

My question is - is there a faster way to do this than just copying the same lines 12 times? I am fairly new at programming in Java, so any insight would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Use arrays and loops.

Comment: All the buttons perform literally the same action, and therefore could use the **same** `ActionListener`. But sure, you can explicitly write out the lambda expression 12 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting your buttons in an array can help a lot

```
final JButton[] buttons = new JButton[12];
final ActionListener myListener = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      if (buttons[i] != ae.getSource()) {
        buttons[i].setText("1");
      }
    }
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  buttons[i] = new JButton();
  buttons[i].setName("Button " + (i + 1));
  buttons[i].addActionListener(myListener);
}
```

Comment: I know this is only an example but it could maybe confuse that the array initializer is missing and myListener is declared after usage

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Acknowledged. I have moved things around

Comment: First of all thank you ... and i dont wanna bother you :) but now you have the same problemes with the buttons declaration :) ... but i think its understandable what you mean with it :)

Comment: @pL4Gu33 I do. It's true. This array really either needs to be declared final, or added as a member of the class. This is all sh** - stuff on computers (the formality) that I have very little patience for these days. It makes me think of how I was working in JavaScript recently, "fixing" a bad kludge of an implementation on the GUI. After I'd fixed the kludge, I needed to fix about four other things - took me two days to work it all out. What I'm getting at is that in programming, many things flow smoothly. But the things that don't... sheesh. Why can't the computer understand what I want????

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this code but it still says that "myListener" cannot be resolved to a variable. I don't want to be annoying, but I would be very grateful if you could elaborate a little more.

Comment: @IgorHeslenji I have added my response again. I don't know why it would say: "myListener cannot be resolved", as myListener is clearly defined at the top

Comment: @ControlAltDel I tried it again, this time it gives me a different error at the end of myListener definition - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement. But when I add the ; the program runs a completely empty frame. I have no idea what is going on, but I still want to thank you for helping me.

Comment: @ControlAltDel It works! Everything is fine now. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to use a method for this kind of situation.  Especially if it is to be used elsewhere.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    frame.add(createButton(i+"", "1"));
}
    
public static JButton createButton(String name,  String init) {
    JButton b = new JButton(name);
    b.addActionListener(ae->b.setText(init));
    return b;
}
```

Other parameters can be added or corrected but it gives you the idea.  You could also pass a lambda expression to the method if need be.